# How to generate rsa key pair in client side using angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, client, rsa, key-generator

I need to know how to generate 'rsa' key-pair on the client-side using angular2. 
I need to generate private/public key pair and save the private key into database and want to use public key inside the client side. How can I implement this?

I found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-rsa-keypair for generating key pair. But its for node? Can I implement it into my client side? If yes how? 
Is any other way to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean with _and save the private key into database_ ?. Do you want to store the key into the IndexedDB in browser?

Comment: i need to store it in my Database MongoDb

Comment: For security reasons it is not recommended to send a private key along the network. If you need it in the server, generate the keypair in the server and send the public key to browser

Answer (score 6):

you must use https://github.com/juliangruber/keypair library

then import it in angular component like

```
import * as keypair from 'keypair';
```

and use library method

```
const pubprivkey = keypair();
console.log(pubprivkey);
```

it will return object of RSA public and private key

```
{ public: '-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIGJAoGBAM3CosR73CBNcJsLvAgMBAAE=\r\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n',
  private: '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nMIICXAIBAAKBgQDNwqLEe9wgTXNHoyxi7Ia\r\nPQUCQCwWU4U+v4lD7uYBw00Ga/xt+7+UqFPlPVdz1yyr4q24Zxaw0LgmuEvgU5dycq8N7Jxj\r\nTubX0MIRR+G9fmDBBl8=\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n' }
```

Comment: Looks good, but is this trustworthy, this library? This is th emain concern here. Otherwise, looks good.